# Normally distributed shift in the independent variable

Tags: distributions, linear

An online game has a system where players can "curse" each other for bad behavior.  The game developer graphs "total hours played v. number of curses" and takes a linear regression. The trend line has a positive slope of M.

Then, she remembers that she "reset" everyone's curse scores to zero at some point in the past. She should really use "total hours played since the reset" as her independent variable but she is very lazy.

What impact does not accounting for reset have on M if:

**A.** All players joined at the same time?

**B.** Players join the game all the time in a roughly uniform distribution including after the reset?

**C.** All players joined at roughly the same time, normally distributed about a date not long after the game was released? Not many players have joined since she reset everyone's curse score to zero.

I'm thinking in the first case that M would not change since it's a linear shift in the independent variable. But the y- intercept of the equation for the regression would be different. For case B, M would be artificially low, provided the rate individuals got cursed was not variable. (lets say it's not)

C is the one I'm most curious about. It's not a linear shift of the independent variable but rather a normally disturbed shift. Is there a theorem about this? If the deviation is small enough it should be like A.... but can we say more than this?

Comment: This reads like an assignment. Please clarify the source of the question (the "A","B", "C" in your post, where you're asking about C). Is this an exercise for some class?

Comment: I made it up myself.

Comment: Probably reads like a question because part of my job is writing questions, but not for stat... jeeez.

Comment: If your wrote it yourself and C is the one you're curious about, why put in the others?

Comment: To give some examples of how the set up works and to find out if my initial reasoning is correct.

Comment: You know context, not just a dangling question.

Comment: The problem is ill defined. If there has been some tampering with the data in the past, anything could have happened. You'd have to assume something, which is pure speculation without data. You could have a "real" (but unknown) relation between the two properties time_played and curses_score. But then again, this could be a random walk, where you'd also get a finite positive distance covered after the nth step.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for some made up data for all 3 scenarios (A, B and C), 10 hours total (numbers are not integers here, but whatever)

[image]

In the following plot we reset the number of curses halfway through

[image]